# Time complexity of nested while loop with if-else

Tags: while-loop, time-complexity

I am getting confused about how to analysis the time complexity within a nested while loop which divide into odd and even situation. could anyone help to explain how to deal with the situation?

```
     i = 1 
     while (i < n) { 
       k = i 
       while ( k < n ) {
         if ( k % 2 == 1 ) 
             k ++ 
         else 
             k = k + 0.01*n
       }
       i = i + 0.1*n
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in a problem like this, the factors 0.01 and 0.1 play a huge role.

First let's consider the inner while loop, if k is odd, we increment k by 1. If k is even, we increment k by one-hundredths of n. How man iterations can this inner while loop run?

Clearly if all iterations were of type-1(odd case), the inner while loop would run n-k times, and similarly if all the iterations were of type-2(even case), the inner while loop would run atmost a 100 times(as we increment the value of k by one-hundredths of n each time).

Given value of k, the number of iterations of the inner while loop is:
max(n-k,100). From now on, we will assume the value of n-k to be greater than 100 always, without loss of generality.

Okay, how does the outer loop iterate? In each iteration of the outer loop, the value of i increases by one-tenths of n each time, so the outer while will run at most 10 times.

Making the running times explicit and calculating the overall running time:

```
Running time for first iteration of outer loop  :   n-k 
Running time for second iteration of outer loop : + n-(k+0.1*n) 
                                                  + n-(k+0.2*n) 
                                                  ... 
                                                  + n-(k+0.9*n)
                                                  -----------
                                                = 10n-10k-(4.5)n
```

Plugging in k=1(as this is the start value of k),
10n-10-4.5n = 5.5 n -10 = O(n)

Hence complexity is O(n) time.

Comment: why for the outer loop it is n-k in the first iteration , (n-k)+0.1n in the second iteration? Also, according to the growing pattern, I assume the 10th iteration should be  (n-k)+0.9n , but why it becomes n-k*0.9*n ( is it n-k*0.9*n or (n-k)*0.9n )? if it will run 10 times for the outer loop, can I just obtain the  worst total running time as 10*(n-k) ?

Comment: @miaomiao2016: The initial value of k in each iteration of inner loop is as follows: n-k, n-(k+0.1*n), n-(k+0.2*n) ... The total running time is the sum of the running times of the inner code of the outer while loop. Sorry, there was a typing mistake before. Check now.